# Error trying to upgrade mongodb to version 3.6 with homebrew

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I'm trying to upgrade mongodb to version 3.6. I ran `brew update` to get any new formulae. Then I ran `brew upgrade mongodb` and it complains that I already have 3.4. Is it possible to upgrade to 3.6 through homebrew, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

`~: brew update
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core, caskroom/cask).
==> New Formulae
ddgr
==> Updated Formulae
qt ✔                dialog              octave              suite-sparse
ansible-lint        fd                  pyenv               sundials
artifactory         graphicsmagick      python-markdown     traefik
ceres-solver        html-xml-utils      reminiscence        wtf
chromedriver        libtiff             sfk
~: brew upgrade mongodb
Error: mongodb 3.4.10 already installed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried this this-morning and go the same error.  I guess it is not yet available via homebrew ☹️

The mongoDB web site has a statement about it being untested on OSX 10.13:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/